# Access SWF and call Actionscript functions from Javascript in IE in Facebook after Facebook dialog pops up

Tags: javascript, facebook, flash, internet-explorer, starling-framework

I'm developing a Facebook game using Flash and Starling and most of the time when a user on IE opens a Facebook Dialog (share/feed/send) I'll lose my ability to make Actionscript calls on the SWF object from Javascript.

As in before the dialog comes up, if I use something like this:

```
swfObj = document.getElementById('mySWF');
swfObj.talkToClient();
```

It works fine and after the dialog is shown, I start getting this error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'talkToClient'
```

It's as if IE forgets that that element is an SWF object or at least forgets about the SWF object callbacks.

I'm embedding Flash using swfobject with these values:

```
        var swfVersionStr = "14";                        
        var xiSwfUrlStr = "playerProductInstall.swf";
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {};
        params.quality = "high";
        params.bgcolor = "#000000";
        params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
        params.allowfullscreen = "true";
        params.allowNetworking = "all";
        params.menu = "false";
        params.wmode = "direct";
        var attributes = {};
        attributes.id = "mySWF";
        attributes.name = "mySWF";
        attributes.align = "middle";

        swfobject.embedSWF(
            "index.swf", "flashContent",
            "827", "620",
            swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr,
            flashvars, params, attributes, swfCallback);           
        swfobject.createCSS("#flashContent", "display:block;text-align:left");
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Are we talking abut a Facebook canvas app here? Facebook will call methods to hide your flash elements as soon as you call their dialogs, because of z-index issues. You need to implement your own handler function to deal with this, if you want to have any say in how exactly this is done. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas/handling-popups#flash_hide_callback, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.hideFlashElement

Comment: Yes, it is a Facebook canvas app.

The only thing is that I'm already using the onFlashHide suggested here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas/handling-popups#flash_hide_callback

And the game is properly being hidden, replaced by a screenshot and resumed on Chrome and Firefox, but not on Internet Explorer.

Comment: I even tried forcing an addCallbacks function inside my swf, so that the SWF would certainly be ready in terms of callbacks, but I keep getting `Object doesn't support property or method 'talkToClient'` when I try to use this code `swfObj = document.getElementById('mySWF');
swfObj.talkToClient();`

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the Facebook Dialogs (as in modal iframes) are the ones that seem to trigger this problem, since opening and closing Facebook's chat seems to successfully hide, replace by a screenshot and resume the game.

Comment: Can you share your app, or set up a test-environment, to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by overriding Facebook's swf hiding behavior in Internet Explorer using the following css piece:

```
*::-ms-backdrop,#mySWF{
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

I'm leaving it here as it might help someone else. It seems like Internet Explorer doesn't like executing a javascript call to an swf obj that is not being shown and if by any chance you make it visible again after making ONE call to a hidden swf, IE continues not being able to execute it.

By not letting the swf object to be hidden, everything works fine :)